# How to record and preserve a user-editable Django model instance at a given time

Tags: python, mysql, django, database

I am working on a Django app where I need to record and preserve a user's details when they complete an action.

To use an analogy, say I have an Address model something like:

```
class Address(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    street = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    town = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    ...
```

And so on. The user can edit their address at any time.

When they complete an action, I need to create a receipt detailing their address at the time.

If I created a `Receipt` model with an `address` field as a `ForeignKey` like so:

```
class Receipt(models.Model):
    ref_num = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    date = models.models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    address = models.ForeignKey(Address, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

The receipt would be correct at the time of creation, but if the user then changed their address, it would be incorrect.

Is the solution to create a `Receipt` model duplicating all of the fields in the `Address` model, so that they can be preserved?

```
class Receipt(models.Model):
    ref_num = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    date = models.models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    street = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    town = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    ...
```

I am assuming there's a less verbose and more elegant way of achieving this. I need to create a snapshot of the user's address at a given moment in time basically, without creating a duplicate `Address`, as these are user editable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way of creating a snapshot without duplicates, you could keep the data to a minimum by only tracking the fields that have changed. But if you do this and you want to know what the address was for an instance you need to loop back over all the changes that where made.

Comment: I suppose I could duplicate the `Address` model instance, with an added field to specify if it was a user-editable address or a receipt address. Only the former would show up in the user's account and be editable.